# Saving the output of telnet comand on multiple devices into a csv file using Python

Tags: python, csv, telnetlib

I made a script in python to telnet a list of ips from a csv file, send a command, print the output of the command and from the output i then print the temperature of the equipment.
How can a save the temperatures and the coresponding ips into a csv file?

```
import telnetlib
import csv
HOST=[]
with open('ips.csv') as fd:
    for row in fd.readlines():
        print row.strip('\n')
        HOST.append(row.strip('\n'))
print HOST 
user = "root"
password = "root"
for i in range(len(HOST)):
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST[i])
    tn.read_until("login: ")
    tn.write(user + "\n")
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")
    tn.write("show slot info\n")
    tn.write("exit\n")
    string = str(tn.read_all())
    print string

    for line in string.splitlines():
        if line.startswith('Temperature                     :'):
            Temperature = line[34:36]
            print Temperature
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same as you read a csv, only writing it:

```
with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerows(Temperature)
```